# Custom navigation menu

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I'm developing a new theme for my Drupal 8 site. As below picture shows, I defined a **header** region and when I add navigation menu to that region, I have both **navigation menu** and default theme navigation in one place.

[image: image of drupal header]

How can I show drupal navigation menu with the theme of my template and eliminate the menu of template?

Thanks

Comment: Which theme are you using ?

Comment: I'm using https://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524962-corlate-free-responsive-business-html-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found it and have this task done.

I went to `/core/themes/stable/templates/menu.html.twig` and put my style (taken from my html template) around followng part of twig file:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <li{{ item.attributes }}>

    {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}

    {% if item.below %}
      {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
    {% endif %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your theme is forcing a menu there through it's page.tpl.php (assuming Drupal 7). It is basically the same as what Bartik does in [Bartik page.tpl.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bartik/tree/templates/page.tpl.php) on lines 127- 138.

Bartik however offers a setting for this on the theme configuration page Configuration > Appearance > Bartik > Settings > Main Menu checkbox.

Your theme might offer a similar checkbox. If it doesn't you'll need to remove the code snippet manually.